# Nulll in where Claus Error The connection for viewings your linked Microsoft Excel worksheet was lost

Tags: sql, excel, vba

```
strCn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
"Data Source=" & FullPath & _
";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"
Set cnEx = New ADODB.Connection
cnEx.Open strCn
Set rs = Nothing

rs.Open " Select [MyCode] from [sheet1$] WHERE [MyCode] IsNull ", cnEx, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

NullCount = rs.RecordCount
```

When including Is Not Null then no Error thrown

Comment: add a space between `IsNull` as `Is Null`

Comment: I Tried that also

Comment: Select [MyCode] from [sheet1$] WHERE [MyCode] Is Not Null  ", cnEx, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly ,this is work fine but  I cannot use WHERE mycode is Null

Comment: Well - use IMEX=1 in your connection string to retrieve mixed data types. `;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0; IMEX=1;`. I believe your datatype of null columns are varchar and doesn't match with your query.

Comment: thanks for your effort but problem is still there

Comment: `Select [MyCode] from [sheet1$] WHERE [MyCode] != ""`

Answer (score 0):

I think you just should be using:

```
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
```

instead of:

```
Set rs = Nothing
```

This works for me:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
    Dim FullPath As String
    Dim strCn As String
    Dim cnEx As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim NullCount As Long

    FullPath = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    strCn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & FullPath & _
    ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
    Set cnEx = New ADODB.Connection
    cnEx.Open strCn
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    rs.Open "Select [MyCode] from [sheet1$] WHERE [MyCode] Is Not Null", _ 
             cnEx, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

    NullCount = rs.RecordCount
    Debug.Print NullCount
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Mincho ,still Problem is there if I alter the query with IS NOT NULL then its Work